# Retrieve Nuget Package Metadata from IFormFile or MemoryStream

Tags: nuget, metadata, nuget-package

I have an API I am creating that retrieves an IFormFile that is a Nuget package.  I need to retrieve the 'BuildVersion-X.X.X.X' value from the metadata.  All the research I have found so far is just retrieving it from a local file path or from a repository.  I have found a way around it to get what I want as shown in the code below, but it is not the most elegant solution as there is a lot of string and manipulation involved.  Is there a better way to retrieve the information I need from the metadata in the Nuspec file?

```
`// If build version is not included, retrieve it from file
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.BuildVersion))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        IFormFile file = request.File;
                        file.Headers.ContentType = "application/zip";

                        Stream unzippedStream = file.OpenReadStream();
                        MemoryStream data = new();
                        string[] packageNameArray = file.FileName.Split('_');
                        string packageName = packageNameArray.First();

                        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(unzippedStream))
                        {
                            zip[$"{packageName}.nuspec"].Extract(data);
                        }
                        data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        byte[] dataArray = data.ToArray();

                        string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataArray);
                        string[] textArray = text.Split("<tags>");
                        string[] otherTextArray = textArray[1].Split("</tags>");
                        string buildVersion = otherTextArray[0];
                        string[] buildVersionArray = buildVersion.Split("-");
                        string currentBuildVersion = buildVersionArray[1];

                        request.BuildVersion = currentBuildVersion;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        request.BuildVersion = null;
                    }`
```

[image: Nuspec Metadata]

I have tried the code above as this has been the only thing that seems to work.  I cannot retrieve the Nuget package from a file path as it is being sent in the API request.  Any suggestions or libraries to do so more elegantly would be appreciated.

Comment: Rather than splitting the string like that, you should use an XML parser. It's more robust as it follows the actual schema of the document. Take a look at `XDocument`, for example. You can then query the value of the `tags` element. Be mindful of the XML namespace when doing this!